# Scrollview always scrolls to the bottom

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I have a view with scrollview as the detailedview of the table cells which is having contents as multiple labels with dynamic size and a couple of buttons which I'm creating through interface builder. Whenever I tap a cell this view is shown to me but the view is always the bottom view. If I scroll up, I'm able to see the content above but when I leave, it again resets its position i.e. the bottom of the view.

Can anybody please help?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by doing:

```
contentView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
```